# Ошибка отсутствия модуля VOSK для распознавания аудио совместно в python3.9.0

Tags: python, аудио, python-3.9

Пытаюсь установить библиотеку VOSK для распознавания речи, чтобы заработал код:

```
from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer  # оффлайн-распознавание от Vosk
```

Установка завершается без ошибок, но импорт опять ругается на отсутсвие модуля vosk.
Установку осуществляю в python3.9.0 с помощью команд:

```
pip3 install vosk
```

и

```
pip install vosk.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Несовместимость версий. Из документации [vosk](https://alphacephei.com/vosk/install):

> Make sure you have up-to-date pip and python3 versions:
>
> **Python version: 3.5-3.8 (Linux)**, 3.6-3.7 (ARM), 3.8-3.9 (OSX), 3.8-64bit (Windows) pip version: 19.0 and newer.